# RecyclerView pushes button into the not visible area

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

The RecyclerView pushes the button under the visible area when there are more than 5 items in it. How can I fix that?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dolinsek.elias.cashcockpit.BankAccountsFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_bank_accounts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_create_bank_accounts"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/create_account"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dolinsek.elias.cashcockpit.BankAccountsFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_bank_accounts"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_create_bank_accounts"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="@string/create_account"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: @EliasDolinsek it's correct answer. Button will take al space it's needed, then recycler view will use space which left.

Comment: How should I do that, it's too long?

Comment: @EliasDolinsek use some service like pastebin or Github's Gist

Answer (score 0):

Try below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dolinsek.elias.cashcockpit.BankAccountsFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_bank_accounts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_create_bank_accounts"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/create_account"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```